# How many home purchase loans can a non-resident Indian get in India?

Tags: india, international, home-loan

I have a housing loan (purchase loan) with a bank in India, which is going very smoothly without any dues. My present salary is approx. 250,000 INR (15,000 UAE dirhams). I would like to purchase one more plot with a house. My existing bank is ready to give another loan, but the tenure I'm looking for is low there.

Can I go for a purchase loan with another bank where the tenure is higher? Will I get one more purchase loan with another bank (after revealing my existing loan)? How many housing loans are available to a non-resident Indian (NRI) in India if the repaying capacity and other qualifications are ok?

Answer (score 2):

There is no restriction by law to get more than one housing loan from either one bank or from multiple banks.

You would need to check with multiple Bank, depending on the Banks Internal Policy guidelines, they can grant or deny you the loan. There are plus and minus of you being an NRI that will have a bearing on loan;

Plus
-  Banks love an NRI, if you are able to show sufficient income [helps further if you are able to show deposits made in India]

Minus
- Very less recourse for Banks incase the loan gets deliquint and hence quite a few Banks avoid this area.
- Possibly No/less Credit Score [CIBIL] as you don't have quite a few lines of credits open.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact date when the government brought in this rule but as of 3rd May 2017, an NRI can own maximum of two properties in India.